# PLSQL declare date like result of query

Tags: plsql

I would like to set variable for date of first monday from sysdate and return this day in put_line but it's not working. I working on oracle database

```
SET serveroutput on;

DECLARE
  first_monday DATE;
BEGIN
  first_monday := select NEXT_DAY(sysdate, 'MONDAY') from dual;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(first_monday);
END;
/
```

result should be `06-04-20`
what is wrong?

my error below

```
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 29:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:
( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
date <a string literal with character set specification>
<a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
<an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
<an alternat
ORA-06550: line 4, column 73:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:
. , @ ; for <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> group having intersect
minus order partition start subpartition union where connect
ORA-06550: line 8, column 0:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
member constructor map
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly call next_day in PL/SQL (no need for a query).  This is desirable because it doesn't cause a context switch between the PL/SQL engine and the SQL engine.  Most, but not all, scalar functions can be used this way.

If you need to use it as part of a query then INTO is used to send a query result value into a variable.

Here are both in action.

```
DECLARE
  first_monday DATE;
BEGIN
  first_monday := next_day(SYSDATE,
                           'MONDAY');

  dbms_output.put_line(first_monday);

  SELECT next_day(SYSDATE,
                  'MONDAY')
    INTO first_monday
    FROM dual;

  dbms_output.put_line(first_monday);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to assign the result of a single row query to a variable in PL/SQL is via the INTO keyword. You need to change your code as follows:

```
DECLARE
  first_monday DATE;
BEGIN
  select NEXT_DAY(sysdate, 'MONDAY')
  INTO first_monday
  from dual;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(first_monday);
END;
```